# How can I search for files by file size using Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, files

How can I search for files by file size using Nautilus (Ubuntu 15.10)?

I want a list of all the big files in one of my hard drives.

I can see the search by file type option by not search by file size.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how using nautilus, usually when you need a more sophisticated file finding capabilites, most people use  the shell program `find`.
this command finds all files bigger than 100Megabytes and prints what each files size is

```
find <the dir you want to look in> -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

obviously replace `<the dir you want to look in>` with the path to the dir you want to search in.

Comment: Well, it should be implemented into Nautilus. It's a no brainer, people need it, Windows has it, sometimes the Terminal is inconvenient. I hope team Ubuntu reads this. Any other way to do it using a GUI? I want to be able to just click on the file to check what it is before deleting it.